# Rcpp: Trouble with linking to Shogun C++ files

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, shogun

I am writing an R package and I am trying to include some of the functionality of the [Shogun toolbox for machine learning](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun). I first included the [shogun folder](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/tree/develop/src/shogun) which contains the C++ functions in the `/inst/include/` folder. I then added the following statements to my `Makevars` and `Makevars.win` files:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS =  -I../inst/include/
```

I then tried a test so in a file called `test.cpp` which I placed in `/src`, and which includes the following:

```
#include <shogun/lib/config.h>
```

and I get the error: `test.cpp: fatal error: shogun/lib/config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a header only package out of a library that is *not* header only.

That is to say in the `/inst/include/` you have a mixture of `.h` and `.cpp`. To rectify this, you should only retain the `.h` files in `/inst/include/`. Keep a copy of the `.h` and `.cpp` together files in `/src`.

The best package to model your package after is [`RcppMLPACK1`](https://github.com/rcppmlpack/RcppMLPACK1) with its use of [`inst/include/`](https://github.com/rcppmlpack/RcppMLPACK1/tree/846596bcf069fd530271c497e8a4b9cbba5c1835/inst/include), [`src/`](https://github.com/rcppmlpack/RcppMLPACK1/tree/846596bcf069fd530271c497e8a4b9cbba5c1835/src), [plugin manager definition](https://github.com/rcppmlpack/RcppMLPACK1/blob/846596bcf069fd530271c497e8a4b9cbba5c1835/R/inline.R), and [linking plus cxx flags](https://github.com/rcppmlpack/RcppMLPACK1/blob/846596bcf069fd530271c497e8a4b9cbba5c1835/R/flags.R).

However, you might just want to create a package that links to system's libraries. e.g. [`RcppMLPACK2`](https://github.com/rcppmlpack/rcppmlpack2). This package uses [`configure.ac`](https://github.com/rcppmlpack/rcppmlpack2/blob/ab5c66a5e58da41cc6f477b10013f2f442330f20/configure.ac), which is the master `autoconf` to generate `configure` to ensure the necessary paths are present. Note of extensions to `autoconf` in the [`m4` directory](https://github.com/rcppmlpack/rcppmlpack2/tree/ab5c66a5e58da41cc6f477b10013f2f442330f20/m4)